# Deletion in the export of an org-link

Tags: org-export, org-link

I have defined an `org-link` as follows:

```
(org-link-set-parameters my-link
 :follow (lambda (path) (message "This my link"))
 :export (lambda (path desc backend) "") ; I need to remove the space before the link.
)
```

In my case, this type of a link is always preceded by a space which should not appear in the exported file. How can I cause the character immediately preceding the link to be deleted during export?

For example, when exporting the following:

`Some text my-link:path more text.`

if the link is simply replaced by an empty string two spaces would result in the output. I want to avoid the extra space.

Comment: Can you post an example of what your link looks like in org, and how you want it to export? You might be able to eliminate the space by using the bracket form of the link like this[[mylink:some path]].

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a backend specific "feature". I see what you see (the extra space) for html and latex export, but not for ascii export. I think you can use a filter to eliminate the space like this:

```
(let ((org-export-filter-link-functions '((lambda (txt _ _) (if (string= txt " ") "" txt)))))
  (org-html-export-as-html))
```

Comment: What will be passed to this filter as `txt`, i.e. when will it be `" "`?

Comment: txt is the "transcoded" link. It is " " when you export the link as "" in html and latex exports as far as I can tell, i.e. they are adding an extra space to it, and the filter just replaces it with "".

Answer (score 0):

Use substring?

```
(substring " http://www.google.com" 1)
```

Test:

```
(message "%s" (substring " http://www.google.com" 1))
```

or is that not what you mean?

Comment: I mean that I want the character before the link not to get exported.

Comment: I edited the question.